# Permissions GCS buckets

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gcp-ai-platform-notebook

I have permissions to create folders and files in a specific bucket (i.e., I can create and move files around in the console). However, when I try to push files to the bucket from a VM located in another project (service account is different), I get:

```
AccessDeniedException: 403 xxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.objects.create access to zzzzzzzzzzzzz
```

How can I let GCS know that I'm the same user?

Comment: Add the service account to the project that owns the bucket and add a role allowing bucket access.

Comment: Your console identity and your VM identity aren't the same. You have the permission, not the VM. Add the service account of the VM as storage admin on your bucket (as @JohnHanley said). In addition, check the scope of your VM to be sure to authorize it to use the storage API

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your VM does not have permissions , so to let your VM have permissions so that it can transfer your files from GCS of one project to other:

1] Create a service account of VM as a role "Storage Admin" in the project where GCS is created.

Reference:

[Steps to create Service Account](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-accounts#creating)

Answer (score 1):

From Error, you are using Default Compute Service Account in Notebook.
In the GCS bucket grant GCS read/write permissions to `xxxxxxxxxxx-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com`